# p5.js Color Array Error Message

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to push colors into an array in p5.js except it won't let me,
here is my code, could someone please tell me why?

```
var colors = [];

colors.push( color(255,  0,  0,  0) );    
colors.push( color(255,127,  0,255) );    
colors.push( color(255,255  ,0,255) );    
colors.push( color(  0,255,  0,255) );
colors.push( color(  0,  0,255,255) );    
colors.push( color( 75,  0,130,255) );    
colors.push( color(148,  0,211,255) );
```

It reports this error:

```
brick.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: color is not defined
at brick.js:2
```

Comment: Because p5.js library isn't ready. Do you import the library? Moreover, your js code must be imported after p5.js

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the p5 function `color` before `setup()` is called. Why this happens is explained in detail [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup).

---

I have made a working example of how you might do it below.

```js
let colors;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(150, 150);
  background(238);
  
  colors = [];
  colors.push( color(255,  0,  0,  0) );    
  colors.push( color(255,127,  0,255) );    
  colors.push( color(255,255  ,0,255) );    
  colors.push( color(  0,255,  0,255) );
  colors.push( color(  0,  0,255,255) );    
  colors.push( color( 75,  0,130,255) );    
  colors.push( color(148,  0,211,255) );
}


function changeColor() {
  background(random(colors));
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='changeColor()'>Choose color from array</button>
```